# ElasticSearch script to compute statistics on array of objects (as part of re-indexing or update by query)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following document stored in ES.

Mapping:

```
"sessions_v4": {
"mappings": {
  "perfData": {
    "properties": {
      "perfSamples": {
        "properties": {
          "perfValue": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      },
      "sessionId": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "version": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is an example document with the above mapping,

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "sessions_v4",
    "_type": "perfData",
    "_id": "AVraIIvbQlFV0tfF1gDd",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "perfSamples": [
        {
          "perfValue": 19,
          "timestamp": 72
        },
        {
          "perfValue": 29,
          "timestamp": 1072
        },
        {
          "perfValue": 30,
          "timestamp": 2072
        },
        {
          "perfValue": 30,
          "timestamp": 3072
        }, 
        ... 
      ] 
   }
```

There are several thousand documents stored, and I am looking for a way to calculate some custom metrics on these documents and add a new field with the new computed metric. For instance, I would like to add "total" perfValue for each document as a new field "perfTotal" along with "perfSamples".

I tried the following script,

```
GET sessions_v4/perfData/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "total_perf": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "int total = 0; for (int i = 0; i < doc['perfSamples'].length; ++i) { total += i; } return total;"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have basically modified the script provided below
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-painless.html

I am getting the following error though,

```
 {
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 4,
    "failed": 1,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "sessions_v4",
        "node": "PG8xNDX3Q2u-vK6EmRI7Ng",
        "reason": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "runtime error",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "No field found for [perfSamples] in mapping with types [perfData]"
          },
          "script_stack": [
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:80)",
            "i = 0; i < doc[‘perfSamples'].length; ++i) { ",
            "               ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script": "int total = 0; for (int i = 0; i < doc[‘perfSamples'].length; ++i) { total += i; } return total;",
          "lang": "painless"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 56127,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

Any ideas? We are just getting started with ES so might be a trivial issue :)

UPDATE: Changed the script to the following and it works.

```
GET sessions_v4/perfData/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "total_perf": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "int total = 0; for (int i = 0; i < doc['perfSamples.perfValue'].values.size(); ++i) { total += i; } return total;"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you're not using the right tick? it should be `'` instead of `‘`

Comment: @Val - I dont think so. I copied the Kibana Console Output to a text editor and the editor did that change from ' to ‘. If you look at the query, it uses the correct tick

Comment: @Val. Solved using the following doc['perfSamples.perfValue'].values.size()